# 90 degree image rotation and reset EXIF rotation

Tags: c#, image-processing, exif

I have code to batch resize digital photos.

Some photos are taken in portrait orientation.

For the photos in portrait orientation, I have to rotate them.

I am using the following C# code to rotate the photo:

```
bmpOrig.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
bmpOrig.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It works fine (displays the way I want in a web browser).

However, if I view the new image in Photoshop (and HP photo viewer) it displays rotated.

I have done a lot of research and I believe there is EXIF data that flags the image is rotated.

**My question is: How do I reset this EXIF data to indicate that the image does not need to be rotated?**

I'm developing in VS 2010.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encodervalue.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See if the `Save` command is actually writing the changes?

maybe make sure by enclosing the `Write` command in a `try/catch` block?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the EXIF info is stored in the Properties of the Image class, so take a look through them and remove the offending one.

Answer (score 1):

The Exif Orientation Tag id is `0x0112`.

You can use `img.GetPropertyItem(0x0112)` to retrieve it and then `img.RemovePropertyItem(0x0112)` to remove it (if you physically rotate the image to compensate that value).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459903/1233379) for a small helper class that does just that (full source code included).